# Categorising values in one column and printing them in a new column in R

Tags: r, categories, calculated-columns

I'm trying to categorize values in a column (Value) based on how it compares to other columns (in this case ColA, ColB, ColC)
The category of the value should be written in the corresponding row under the column 'Category'.

Below is an example of the dataframe

```
Value   ColA    ColB    ColC    Category
0.8     0.3     0.7     1.1 
0.1     0.2     0.7     1.3 
0.7     0.5     0.8     1.0
```

Here is essentially pseudocode of what I'm trying to say:

```
if ( Value >= 0 && Value <= ColA {
    print("Bottom") in Category
}
else if(Value > ColA && Value <= ColB){
    print("Middle") in Category
}
else if(Value > ColB && Value <= ColC){
    print("Top") in Category
}
else(){
}
```

I'm just starting to learn R however and am struggling with the syntax. How is this achieved in R?

Comment: You can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` i.e. `with(df1, ifelse(Value >= 0 & Value <= ColA, "Bottom", ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

importing your data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 Value   ColA    ColB    ColC
                 0.8     0.3     0.7     1.1 
                 0.1     0.2     0.7     1.3 
                 0.7     0.5     0.8     1.0", header = T)
```

Now we can use a set of nested `ifelse`-statements:

```
df$Category <-
  ifelse(df$Value >= 0 & df$Value <= df$ColA, "Bottom",
    ifelse(df$Value > df$ColA & df$Value <= df$ColB, "Middle",
      ifelse(df$Value > df$ColB & df$Value <= df$ColC, "Top", NA)
    )
  )
```

Output:

```
> df
  Value ColA ColB ColC Category
1   0.8  0.3  0.7  1.1      Top
2   0.1  0.2  0.7  1.3   Bottom
3   0.7  0.5  0.8  1.0   Middle
```

From `?ifelse`:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

An alternative, more readable solution:

```
df$Category <- NA

df$Category[df$Value >= 0 & df$Value <= df$ColA] <- "Bottom"
df$Category[df$Value > df$ColA & df$Value <= df$ColB] <- "Middle"
df$Category[df$Value > df$ColB & df$Value <= df$ColC] <- "Top"

> df
  Value ColA ColB ColC Category
1   0.8  0.3  0.7  1.1      Top
2   0.1  0.2  0.7  1.3   Bottom
3   0.7  0.5  0.8  1.0   Middle
```

Comment: This is helpful--I appreciate you walking through the steps and showing an alternative solution